# Getting the addresses of all currently used variables with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I know that it is possible to output the names of all global and static variables (and their size in case of static arrays) using the command `info variables` in gdb.
I also know that the address of a variable can be displayed using `info address`.

Is it possible to display a list of all addresses at which variables are stored?
This could be used for example to know which array is stored in memory just before a corrupted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For globals you don't need gdb for this.

Just to nm -n yourbinary.

Comment: Interesting, I always assumed that the addresses could only be defined at runtime (depending on how much memory is already used by other applications). Thank you very much!